# How to strictly enforce margin boundaries?

Tags: margins

My question appears to be the same as [Enforce strict margin boundaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256526/enforce-strict-margin-boundaries)
Yet, my problem is more than just left and right margin issues. Like the other poster, I'm working to finalize my dissertation and have a 600+ page document.

The additional issues that are being encountered are **bottom margin violations**.
This happens when a line has lowercase letters such as p and g and the bottom portion goes outside the bottom margin.

The second issue is that sometimes an **equation is the bottom line and completely violates the margins**. The third unaddressed issue is that sometimes the right margin is violated just a little bit.

I agree that these issues are minor and will not detract from the overall look of the document, yet graduate office personnel love to make a practice out of being zealots for margins because it is easy to check and there is a clear dividing line.

I used the use package command: `\usepackage[letterpaper,showframe]{geometry}`
to display the margins.

[image: bottom margin violation due to letters]
[image: bottom margin violation due to an equation]
[image]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373120/2388

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The depth of the last box on a page is allowed to stick into the bottom margin by at most `\maxdepth`, see Ulrike's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373120/2388). The rationale is to have the same bottom base line of facing pages.

`\maxdepth` applies to all boxes at the bottom of a page including simple text lines and math equations.

The left and right margins can be violated by a feature called "protruding", see package `microtype`. The idea is that some glyphs (with smaller black pixel percentages) stick a little bit into the margin. The effect should be a visually smoother appearance of the margin.

Some letters, especially in italics fonts, like the italics "f", stick out of its character bounding box. This should optimize the inner-character spacing.
The price is that such a glyph can stick into the right margin.

Overfull `\hbox` and `\vbox` and warnings should be resolved. Otherwise the overfull boxes can stick into the right and bottom margin by larger amounts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and great information. Ulrike's answer was right on although I needed to figure out which \usepackage \maxdepth was part of. This link helped me see how to properly set it. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179718/how-to-have-a-precise-control-on-the-size-of-each-page

Comment: I used showframe to see a lot of the overfull \hbox and \vbox warnings and resolve them. Most of them were figures that violated the margins. I still have a long list of them and I'm not sure what is causing the remaining warnings. Do you have any advice on how to troubleshoot and resolve overfull box warnings?

Comment: @user3780514 Either use class option `draft` (standard classes) or use `\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}`. Then a black bock appears at the right side of overfull `\hbox`es.

Comment: I also found this discussion useful for understanding \fussy and \sloppy... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241343/what-is-the-meaning-of-fussy-sloppy-emergencystretch-tolerance-hbadness

Comment: +1 Good to know. *"The rationale is to have the same bottom baseline of facing pages."* Is that not also true/possible if `\maxdepth` is zero?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Compare a last line without descenders (e.g. `lacus vel est. Curabitur consectetuer.`) with a last line with descenders (e.g. `adipiscing quis,`).