# Page body exceeds page bottom with geometry package

Tags: koma-script, geometry, overflow

In some circumstances, a tabular overflows/exceeds the page bottom that has been set with the `geometry` package. Originally, I've had the problem with a longtable and bunch of different packages, settings, and text, but I've managed to reproduce it with a regular tabular and a meticulously chosen `vspace*` parameter together with the `showframe` option. Here's the MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\geometry{top=2cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{737.6pt}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
X & 0 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered Minimum Working Example]

How do I prevent the page body from exceeding the page bottom using the geometry package, independently of the body content?

Comment: Well with your code you are forcing the tabular out of the page. But beside this, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373120/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer For the MWE, `\maxdepth=0pt` generates a new page with the same behaviour. When applying it to my actual (longer) document, there is no difference. The longtable cell still overflows the page bottom. Guess I will have to re-adjust the MWE. Should I edit the question or create a new one?

Comment: Well yes, as I said,  your page is too large,  and so you are forcing an overflow.